# How to use a variable used in 'for' loop PHP?

Tags: php, variables, for-loop

when using a for loop in PHP are the variables used inside available outside of the loop and if not is there a way of doing so?

```
foreach ($rows as $row){
    $name = $row ['surname'];
    $validpassword = ($validpassword + 1);
}
```

Will I be able to use $validpassword outside of the loop?

Comment: Yes you are! Just try it out :D BTW: A short form of this: `$validpassword = ($validpassword + 1);` would be: `$validpassword++;`

Answer (score 3):

Yes, the variable scope is not limited to the loop.